# Add new column to Multi Index DataFrame Based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a MultiIndex dataframe composed of an Index made up of the address of a store, and status of an order. The values are composed of the number of orders where corresponding to status of the order. So for example, one store might have 6 delivered and 2 cancelled orders.

I want to make a new column that calculates a percentage based on how many orders were cancelled, relative to the number of orders. How would I go about this? For example, if there are no cancelled orders, the percentage would be 0.

Example of the table:

```
store_address   final_status    number_of_orders
190             DeliveredStatus 10
191             DeliveredStatus 8
193             CanceledStatus  1
                DeliveredStatus 1
194             DeliveredStatus 12
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include sample input along with excepted output and code snippet of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have now included the Multi Index table I generated from my query. My inclination is to use np.where to populate a new column based on the other values, however I'm not sure how to be program it so that it can "see" both the stores with two addresses, and those with only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with this sample df

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
'''store_address   final_status    number_of_orders
190             DeliveredStatus 10
191             DeliveredStatus 8
193             CanceledStatus  1
193             DeliveredStatus 1
194             DeliveredStatus 12''')).set_index(['store_address', 'final_status'])
```

You can unstack `final_status` so it is the column index instead of part of the row index. Then you can easily get the percentage.

```
df = df.squeeze().unstack(fill_value=0)
df['cancelled_rate'] = df.CanceledStatus.div(df.sum(axis=1))
```

Output

```
final_status   CanceledStatus  DeliveredStatus  cancelled_rate
store_address
190                         0               10             0.0
191                         0                8             0.0
193                         1                1             0.5
194                         0               12             0.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `cancelled_rate` for `store_address == 193` be `0.5`? Since one order was cancelled and another was delivered, giving a total of 2 orders?

Comment: @IanThompson yes it should, thank you, it is fixed now

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution, I think this is spot on with what I want. I'll try to implement it now. My apologies I don't have enough score to upvote!

Comment: you have the option of selecting it as accepted answer, the you can upvote, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ll=[{'data': 'alex','d':3,'c':0},{'data': 'bc','d':2,'c':1},{'data': 'x','d':4,'c':1},{'data': 'ex','d':1,'c':1}]

df=pd.DataFrame(ll)
df['pct']=np.where(df['c']==0, 0, (df['c']/(df['d']+df['c']))*100)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your starting `df` looks like this:

```
                               number_of_orders
store_address final_status                     
190           DeliveredStatus                10
191           DeliveredStatus                 8
193           CanceledStatus                  1
              DeliveredStatus                 1
194           DeliveredStatus                12
```

Do the following:

```
# unstack final_status and fill_value with 0
df_unstacked = df.unstack(fill_value=0)

print(df_unstacked)

              number_of_orders                
final_status    CanceledStatus DeliveredStatus
store_address                                 
190                          0              10
191                          0               8
193                          1               1
194                          0              12

# calculate CanceledProportion
df_unstacked['CanceledProportion'] = df_unstacked.number_of_orders.CanceledStatus / df_unstacked.sum(axis=1)

print(df_unstacked)

              number_of_orders                 CanceledProportion
final_status    CanceledStatus DeliveredStatus                   
store_address                                                    
190                          0              10                0.0
191                          0               8                0.0
193                          1               1                0.5
194                          0              12                0.0
```

Comment: It is nice to see other people finding the same solutions